# Listen to child_changed (Firebase Realtime Database) on web

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in javascript and firebase, I have created single web page in that I want to listen **child_changed** event
below is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.0.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script>

var config = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAqPnuP-EwU2WXreJ_3Ks_er0KbTKE-BNg",
  authDomain: "hellofirebase-a1794.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://hellofirebase-a1794.firebaseio.com"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

var commentsRef = firebase.database().ref().child('hellofirebase-a1794');

commentsRef.on('child_changed', function(data) {
window.alert("sometext"+data.val());
});       
</script>   
</body>
 </html>
```

My database structure is like below

```
hellofirebase-a1794
               |
               |
               ------betteryLevel : 12
```

but I am not getting event when I change value from Firebase Console, also not getting any error in console of chrome, anybody please help me what is the problem

Comment: Do you see any error in console?

Comment: yes I am not getting any error

Comment: please show your database structure

Comment: updated with database structure, :) thanks for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code from

```
var commentsRef = firebase.database().ref().child('hellofirebase-a1794');
```

to:

```
var commentsRef = firebase.database().ref().child('/');
```

You dont need to add `hellofirebase-a1794`(your root) to your database reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) it is working now, how did you get this, because in docs also I have not found this

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `hellofirebase-a1794` is your project name or is the root, so you do not need to give child after `.ref()`.

You can get your database reference as:

```
var commentsRef = firebase.database().ref();
```

Then you can get your data from `commentsRef`.

Answer (score 0):

This code for use in Node.js

```html
const { getDatabase, ref, onChildAdded } = require('firebase/database');

const db = getDatabase();
    
onChildAdded(ref(db, 'compliments/received/' + currentUser._id), (snapshot) => {
        
    console.log(snapshot.val())
        
})
```